# Im not sure if my code works and i don't know how to test it

Tags: sql, constraints, alter-table

Ignore the names of everything, they're in Croatian. Im not sure if the logic of my alter tables and constraints are correct and if the syntax is properly written. If someone could check I would be very grateful.

---

This is the code

```
CREATE DATABASE Radionice1;
use Radionice1;

create table Ucenik
(
    Sifra_ucenika int not null,
    Ime varchar(20) not null,
    Prezime varchar(20) not null,
    Mjesto varchar(50) not null,

    constraint Ucenik_PK primary key(Sifra_ucenika),
    constraint Sifra_ucenika_chk CHECK (Sifra_ucenika between 1 and 1000)
);
create table Aktivnost
(
    Sifra_aktivnosti int not null,
    Naziv varchar(50) not null,

    constraint Aktivnost_PK primary key(Sifra_aktivnosti),
);
create table Evidencija
(
    Sifra_polazika int not null,
    Sifra_aktivnosti int not null,

    constraint Evidencija_FK foreign key(Sifra_polazika) REFERENCES Ucenik(Sifra_ucenika),
    constraint Evidencija_FK foreign key(Sifra_aktivnosti) REFERENCES Aktivnst(Sifra_aktivnosti),
);
ALTER TABLE Ucenik ADD Datum_rodenja DATE,
ALTER TABLE Ucenik DROP CONSTRAINT Ucenik_chk,
ALTER TABLE Aktivnost ADD Trajanje TIME,
ALTER TABLE Aktivnost ADD CONSTRAINT Trajanje_chk CHECK (Trajanje between 2 and 10),
ALTER TABLE Aktivnost ADD Uvjet INT,
ALTER TABLE Aktivnost ADD CONSTRAINT Uvjet_chk CHECK (Uvjet>10),
ALTER TABLE Ucenik ALTER COLUMN Prezime nvarchar(30),
ALTER TABLE Ucenik DROP Mjesto,
```

Comment: Hard to grasp why first create tables and then heavily alter them without further explanation of what is the goal.

Comment: Second alter table would probably not work since there's no such constraint. At least not in the create table part.

Comment: Why not just execute them and see if there are any syntax errors? And then try add some data which violates the constraints. This should throw an error